# Zoo::yearmon class: removing records that do not contain all months for a given year

Tags: r, date, dataframe, zoo

I have a data frame in R that includes city names, years, and months. It looks like the following:

[Sample data set with Month, Year, and City columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBeY5.png)

This table continues for thousands of records. Some cities do not have data for every month in the year (e.g. the 1920 data for Los Angeles in the example above only contains January and February), meaning they are incomplete. I want to extract out only those years which are complete for a given city (e.g. contains all 12 months for that year, like Toronto in the above example).

I have tried converting it into the zoo::yearmon class, but I do not know how to manipulate it to do what I have described above. I believe that a script could be written that looks at the year and city name, checks if it contains all 12 months, and then omits years that do not.

Comment: Please share your data using `dput()`. [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can we assume that for `City` + `Year`, a `Month` doesn't occur more than once? For example there is only one Jan, 1922, Toronto?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using the `dplyr` package:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(City, Year) %>% 
  filter(length(unique(Month)) == 12)
```

I group by `City` and `Year` and then filter for those with 12 unique months. (I assume your data frame is called `df`.)

---

Now, if you just want a particular city, say Toronto, you could use the following:

```
df %>% 
  filter(City == "Toronto") %>%
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  filter(length(unique(Month)) == 12)
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[uniqueN(Month)==12], .(City, Year)]
```

Comment: This also worked. Thanks for taking the time to answer! I'm not sure which approach is better though.